# Why upgrading Tomcat to version 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.6 breaks session persistence?

Tags: apt, upgrade, session, tomcat7

I have Tomcat 7 on Ubuntu 14.04. Last week I installed the Ubuntu security updates through apt-get, as I always do, and it upgraded Tomcat to version 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.6 (not sure what the previous version was, most likely 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.5 since I update on a regular basis). Ever since that upgrade, session persistence is broken in Tomcat, meaning that all user sessions get killed when I restart Tomcat or the webapp.

This used to work fine. So I tried downgrading the Tomcat packages. I didn't find a way to downgrade to "7.0.52-1ubuntu0.5" so I downgraded to "7.0.52-1" instead:

```
sudo apt-get install tomcat7=7.0.52-1
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-admin=7.0.52-1
sudo apt-get install tomcat7-common=7.0.52-1
sudo apt-get install libtomcat7-java=7.0.52-1
```

As soon as I did this, session persistence started to work again. I tried this on a different computer and the result was the same. I tried upgrading again and the problem was back. So there really seem to be something in this update that breaks session persistence.

I tried it after each step while downgrading the 4 packages listed above, and it only started to work after the last step was done, so maybe the problem is with the libtomcat7-java package.

Any idea how to fix this without having to downgrade the packages? Where should I look next? Should I open a bug with Ubuntu? Or with Tomcat?

Comment: FWIW, I am running into the same problem. I am observing 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.3 works (there doesn't appear to be any 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.5). You can check out the changelog at http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/t/tomcat7/tomcat7_7.0.52-1ubuntu0.6/changelog. But I haven't been able to correlate anything yet (other than there were definitely security changes to sessions in the latest version).

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be working in Tomcat 7.0.52-1ubuntu0.7 now. I don't see anything relevant to the issue in the changelog (unless it has something to do with https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tomcat7/+bug/1609819). But this new version is working for me. Give it a try.